# GridObjectDataSource DataTable Sorting with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My trouble is I do not know howto pass events to sort my DataTable.
I have listed the .aspx page, and the flow of the behind .cs file for the BindThrottles function. I am looking for a simple solution that uses a DataTable. I saw other code that looked simple that used events that I posted at the end, but not sure howto get into that form to use.

My .aspx page is configured as..

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GridObjectDataSource" 
    runat="server"  SelectMethod="BindThrottles"                                                            
    TypeName="WebsiteNamespace.ThrottleInterval" 
    SortParameterName="SortBy">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvThrottles" 
         Name="sortDirection" PropertyName="SortDirection" />
  </SelectParameters>

</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:GridView   ID="gvThrottles" AllowSorting="True" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="UserID" DataSourceID="GridObjectDataSource"
>

 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USERID" SortExpression="USERID">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblItemUserId" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Eval("USERID") %>'></asp:Label>             
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requests" SortExpression="REQUESTS">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblItemNumRequests" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Eval("REQUESTS") %>'></asp:Label>              
      </ItemTemplate>
 </Columns>  

</asp:GridView>
```

My BindThrottles method is configured...

```
public DataTable BindThrottles(string SortBy, int sortDirection){

    //..code to run queries from MongoDB
    //..code to create columns and rows of DataTable
    //..code to fill the rows with the data from the MongoDB

    *************************************************************
    //.. I need some code here to let my DataTable sort on 
    //.. the column header link for Asc or Desc.
    *************************************************************
}
```

I saw another stackoverflow post that shows code like...

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " +
    GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
```

and the GetSortDirection is configured as

```
public string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {

        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }
        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

But I don't know how to get it into a form that can use events to sort inside a function that already has set parameters that are not events, or if there is a better way to sort both ASC and DESC by the Column Header link.

Additional Information: 
  I am very new to ASP. I inherited this project, which is why the function is still currently called BindThrottles, even thought I am trying to eliminate binding(co-workers advice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this function the SortExpression is the Column name and the SortDirection is order to sort ie(Ascending or Descending ). As both the values are stored in ViewState you can use it in any event.You can use this function like this :

```
    DataView dv = new DataView(dtTable);
    dv.Sort = columnName + " " + GetSortDirection(columnName);
    GridView1.DataSource = dv;
    dtTable = dv.ToTable();
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Where dtTable is the DataTable